# Mouse Events in custom class

Tags: c#, mouseenter

I made a custom class object and try to make mouse events (click, move, up/down) for it. This instance of the class is created in the control of the main form, taking the coordinates of this control, as well as all other components of the MouseEventArgs. Here is part of the class and form code:

```
public class CircleFigure
{
    public delegate void MouseEnterCircle(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
    public delegate void MouseClickCircle(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);

    public event MouseEnterCircle MouseEnter;
    public event MouseClickCircle MouseClick;

    protected void Enter(Point CursorPos)
    {
        if (MouseEnter != null)
        {
            MouseEnter(this, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 0, CursorPos.X, CursorPos.Y, 0));
        }
    }

    protected void MouseClickCir(MouseButtons Button, int ClicksCount, int X,int Y)
    {
        if (MouseClick != null)
        {
            MouseClick(this, new MouseEventArgs(Button, ClicksCount, X ,Y , 0));
        }
    }
public Point CursorLocation
{
    get
    {
        return CursorLocation_;
    }
    set
    {
        Enter(new Point(CursorLocation_.X, CursorLocation_.Y));
    }           
}
```

As I said the CursorLocation is taken from the control of mainform:

```
private void DrawControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    s.CursorLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
}
```

So, i would like to ask you how to make own MouseEvent in CircleFigure class? hope for your help

Comment: Cleanest way would be to use the existing [RoutedEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview) WPF provides. Simply inherit from `Control` (`CircleFigure : Control`) and you should have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the problem is that the Control has a lot of properties, which is critical for the program, and they will not be used. Of course, use as a solution will be very convenient, but I held it for more "delicate". I believed that WinAPI has some solutions, but has not found anything yet (Maybe, probably, most likely, I'm doing something wrong (

Comment: May be you could help to get CircleFigure inheriting by suggesting a link to read how to make events inside this?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your end-goal is, but in addition to the one I linked in my original comment, these should get you started: [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx), [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-wf-control-design-time-features)